# Suppose you were hacked and harassed using the data stolen

Tags: hacking, harassment, fbi

Theoretical situation for a cybersecurity course discussion (something of a table-top game):

Suppose you are researching a politically controversial topic and someone hacks your computer and starts collecting your browsing history and personal information. Then they use it to discretely harass you. For example, you receive e-mail, mail or texts coming from or addressed to names involved in your research (e.g., if it were chemistry, you might get a postcard addressed to "Lavoisier" or a text asking you to participate in a study of a new erectile dysfunction drug), or your address book is stolen and your boss gets an inappropriate text from someone with the same first name as you. This continues without you being able to get any idea of the source. None of it is directly threatening so it's not something that makes sense to call 9-1-1 over. You don't want to be a "Karen" or be a man in front of cops complaining about the names printed on your mail, and your friends and family laughed it off a long time ago. But after a few years and some "bad luck" you wonder whether these things have been more than just "gags". You submit an FBI report through an online form but never hear anything back. What kind of lawyer do you seek? What are your legal options?

Answer (score 4):

There is really no point in hiring a lawyer until you can identify a culprit. Lawyers can't sue people until they have a way to serve the person at fault with legal process.

You need an IT professional instead.